# grouped by more than one year old

Tags: doctrine

I have a list of prodcut archive and I'm using dotrine and symfony,I hoped to show list of archive product :

```
   $query = Doctrine::getTable('Product')
            ->createQuery('a')
            ->select('a.created_at, YEAR(a.created_at) as year, MONTH(a.created_at) as month')
            ->groupBy('year, month')
            ->orderBy('a.created_at DESC')
            ->setHydrationMode(Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY)
            ->execute();
```

So I hope to change the query so when is more than 1 year old it should group added Product by year?

**Edit** :

I added this but I guess it's dosn't work with doctrine 1 :

```
->andWhere("year <= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), 1, 'YEAR')")
```

I get this error :

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1, 'YEAR')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can define different `groupBy` clauses in a single select. You can, however, do one of the following:

`(1)` Build 2 independent queries - one for >1 year and the other for <1 year. Then, since you are hydrating to arrays anyway merge your arrays using `array_merge`.

`(2)` Use an SQL `UNION` to merge the results of your two queries. Unfortunately, `doctrine2` does not support `UNION`, so you need to fall back to standard `SQL` (see [here](http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/mv/msg/23556/87836/index.html))

The only open point left is that, if you want the results of both queries to look the same, you need to add a default value for the month in your "older than 1 year" query.

Comment: You can see my modificarion in my message above

Comment: maybe use `->andWhere("year <= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)")`?